# Display PHP values to a page that doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if it was at all possible to modify a page that doesn't refresh (I'm using Ajax) via PHP.

It sounds like a stupid question, and I'm 99.999999% sure it's not possible. The only way I could think of doing it was if I were to output an array with the values and use javascript to modify the page.

I need to return multiple things, which is why I didn't want to use javascript and communicate with ajax, but I think an array is the only choice.

```
if(isset($_FILES['payload'])) {
$file = $_FILES['payload'];
try {
$file['name'] = htmlentities($file['name']);
  $name = $file['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$finfo = new finfo;
$fileinfo = htmlentities($finfo->file(htmlentities($file['tmp_name']), FILEINFO_MIME));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "NULL NAME";
}
  if($extension == 'exe' && (substr($fileinfo, 0, 15) == 'application/exe' || substr($fileinfo, 0, 21) == 'application/x-dosexec')) {
try {
  /*
   * Encryption Removed
   */
  mkdir("REMOVED");
  move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "REMOVED");
  $td[0] = filesize("REMOVED");
  $td[1] = htmlentities($file['name']);
  $td[2] = $fileinfo;
  echo "NULL NULL";
} catch(Exception $e2) {
  echo "NULL ENCRYPTION";
}
} else echo "NULL FILESTATUS";
```

The above is what I currently have, I apologise for the poor formatting.
$td is the array that contains information about the file - which is what I need to return to javascrpt, but I also need to return another variable which is either NULL FILESTATUS, NULL ENCRYPTION, NULL NAME or NULL NULL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, an array is your best bet. JSON encoded, nonetheless.

```
$ret = array();
$ret['status'] = true/false;
```

Then change your `echo` statements to be the `message`

```
$ret['message'] = 'NULL NAME';
$ret['message'] = 'NULL FILESTATUS';
$ret['message'] = 'NULL NULL ENCRYPTION';
$ret['message'] = 'NULL NULL';
```

Then add the file info as a sub array.

```
$ret['file'][0] = filesize("REMOVED");
$ret['file'][1] = htmlentities($file['name']);
$ret['file'][2] = $fileinfo;
```

Finally, return the array encoded as JSON to your javascript.

```
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Then your ajax function should look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET/POST',
    url: 'path/to/my/script.ext',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
        if(response.status == true){
            //handle the rest of the returned array
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I knew how to do it, just curious if it was the best way.
Nonetheless, thanks very much! :)

Comment: Only thing that bothers me on this is we don't know if the OP uses JQuery So it would be good to maybe add an exemple of AJAX using XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject or something... But that's might be just me being picky

Comment: @Sebastien Question is tagged with jQuery. :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Oh sorry my bad didn't checked the tag. You deserve a Upvote for telling me.

Comment: @Kondax Design if the case is just one of code review the question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty common, you're right that PHP can't directly update the page once it's served. If that's what you want to do, it can't be done.

However it's pretty easy with AJAX, it's what you do with AJAX really. Try using PHP's json_encode on an object with the information you want to use, then grab that page with AJAX, and use javascript to update the related page elements. You could also check out [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) to make that process much easier.

Comment: This is what I was doing at the start, I'll be sure to do this.
Thanks! :)